# How to execute a function for "t" time without delay + using external interrupt + Arduino

Tags: function, time, arduino, interrupt

After some research inside Stack Overflow and Google, I've a lot of questions about time management with Arduino, so I've decided to ask you for some help.

The goal is to create a switch case loop inside "void loop()" that execute a certain subroutine for a certain time (for example, three minutes). The pseudocode I've thought up is:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Waiting for command");
}

void loop() {
    // This is where the "polling" occurs
    if(Serial.available()){
        char ch=Serial.read();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1':
            // do something
            break;

            case '2':
            //do something
            break;

            case '3':
            void Tempfunct();
            break;

            default:
            Serial.print(ch);
            Serial.println(" : unknown command!");
        }
    }
}

// Function to be called
void Tempfunct() {
    //Do something for  3*60*60*1000 s and return to switch case selection
}
```

I consider this solution a starting point, because I think a solution involving interrupts would be a better solution. Specifically I expect something like this pseudocode:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Waiting for command");
}

void loop() {
    // This is where the "polling" occurs
    if(Serial.available()){
        char ch=Serial.read();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1':
                // Do something
                break;

            case '2':
               // Do something
               break;

            case '3':
                void Tempfunct();
                break;

            default:
                Serial.print(ch);
                Serial.println(" : unknown command!");
        }
    }
}

// Function to be called
void Tempfunct() {
   //Do something until an interrupt condition is received 
   //from Serial (such a key pressed by user) and then 
   //return to switch case selection.
}
```

How can I do it?

For me, this situation is like having a sort of "measurement loop" inside one of the "case"'s. When the Arduino receives a preset "start-key" (start character), it starts measuring. When the user press another button in the serial monitor (or hyper terminal), it sends a preset "stop-key" (stop character) to the Arduino: the Arduino feels like to have an external interrupt, stops the measurement and return to void loop(){...} cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to do but I would suggest a very simple [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) and for something like this basically a switch statement based on your app 'state'.

As for doing something for a specific period of time, you can just capture the current milliseconds into a variable and then test, as the program runs, if the current milliseconds - stored milliseconds >= your delay period.

Here's some code:

```
#define IDLE  0; //better to use enum; oh well
#define RED   1;
#define BLUE  2;

int programState;
long delayPeriod;
long startTime;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Waiting for command");

  programState = IDLE;
  delayPeriod = (1000 * 60) * 3; // 3 minutes
}

void loop() {

  switch(programState){
  case IDLE:
    checkSerial();
    break;

  case RED:
    // need to handle millis rollover eventually, depending on
    //what the program is doing
    if (millis() - startTime >= delayPeriod){
      programState = IDLE;
    } 
    else {
      //do your thing 

      // to make this interruptable move the 'checkSerial()' call
      // out of the switch - so that it gets called every loop
    }
    break;

  case BLUE:

    break;
  }
}


void checkSerial(){
  // this is where the "polling" occurs
  if(Serial.available()){
    char ch=Serial.read();
    switch(ch){
    case '1':
      programState = RED; //set state
      startTime = millis(); //store current milisecond
      break;

    default:

    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your proposal is one valid option, without using interrupts. But as you said, you need that "your thing" does not block and thus checkSerial() function can be called in time in the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to have a set of commands (available from Serial port) which execute different parts of code, depending on the keys. So if you start doing some staff (i.e. execution of function "Tempfunct"), your question is how to interrupt what are you doing in order to get back to the switch part (which takes care of the user input).

I would like to re-write your question. What you want to know, is how to execute code and at the same time take care of the user input. The typical solution is to use interrupts. You need to specify one interrupt vector (function which deals with interruption, with AVR-Compiler you can use the reserved word SIGNAL), which should be triggered whenever a new character comes.

Your question is easy to answer: The Serial Library from Arduino already make use of interrupts in the serial port. If you have a look at the [implementation of this Library](http://code.google.com/p/arduino/source/browse/trunk/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp?r=972), you can see how it works. There is a ring buffer storing the characters which have not been read. Whenever a new character comes, the interrupt is triggered and the character is saved into this ring buffer by the interrupt vector, so you can read it later with Serial.read() function. Depending on the microcontroller (which Arduino board are you using?) you may have more interrupts. For instance, the Arduino Mega (4 Serial Ports) needs four serial interrupt vectors: SIG_USART0_RECV, SIG_USART1_RECV, SIG_USART2_RECV and SIG_USART3_RECV.

You need to re-write this interrupt vector again in your project (your current sketch) and add some custom code inside. The interrupt vector is like any other function. Be careful not to add too much code, only regular checks.

I am not 100% sure, but if you include two interrupt vectors in the same project, I guess the second (your main code) will overwrite the first one (library). But I recommend you to try first, just in case.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! I would like to create a code similar to that shown you above: a switch case loop, in which one case execute a subroutine that control a sensor for pressure measurement. My Arduino Uno should take data from the sensor until it receive a "stop-character" (a key is pressed by the user, using the serial monitor or something like Processing) and then return to the "switch case loop". In the "switch case loop" there are some other subroutines, which can be call pressing other "call-character" (even sent with the serial monitor or with Processing), and do something else.

Comment: My proposal is valid, but you still have another one which use no interrupts. It is up to you!

Comment: Could anyones help me to solve this problem?? I've yet tried "Time.h" and "TimeAlarms.h" library and they don't fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I  understand what you are asking correctly, you would like to make it so that when you enter a "start key" into the Serial monitor your Arduino will enter a measurement state or loop. To do that just write an if statement. Use the Serial.read() command to get input from the Serial monitor then save that to a variable. Then use the if statement to check the contents of the variable and if it is the one you want to be your start key then it will go into the if statement and you can have a loop in the if statement that will loop and take your measurements. When you are ready for the measurements to end you do a similar process. Have a Serial.read() function that saves into a variable and have another if statement so that when the "end key" you decide is pressed it will break from the measurement loop.
ie:

```
 input = Serial.read();
    if(input == '1')
    {
      while(true)
      {
      measurment();
      input_2 = Serial.read();
      if(input_2 == '2')
        break;
      }
    }
```